# Window moving when debug stepping in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

When debugging in Eclipse, pressing "Step Over" keeps moving my window's scroll position so that the method declaration is at the top of the view. Unless the instruction pointer is so low that the method declaration can't be seen, then it keeps moving my window's scroll position every time I step.

I want it to just leave my window where it is, and only move when the instruction pointer moves off screen. Example:

[image: Before Stepping]

[image: After stepping]

I swear Eclipse used to work like I'm describing here, but I recently installed the latest Oxygen on a fresh workspace and now it's doing this and driving me bonkers.

Is there some setting where I can change this behaviour?

Thanks!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue with a plain _Eclipse IDE for Java Developers_ (Oxygen.1a) without additional plug-ins. Maybe it is caused by an additional plug-in you have installed (for example the Darkes Dark Theme patches the Eclipse platform via bytecode weaving including the scrollbars).

Comment: Thanks howlger for verifying this, see my answer below; I believe Darkest Dark was the culprit. I had uninstalled all my plugins, deleted my workspace, reinstalled eclipse, so I thought I had cleared everything to rule out my plugins as the source of the issue, but I'm guessing there was some setting they had applied that was messing things up.

Answer (score 1):

Can confirm: As howlger mentioned, this was somehow related to installing some plugin, probably Darkest Dark. Uninstalling eclipse and deleting my project workspace wasn't sufficient to restore functionality, I also had to delete the .eclipse, .webclipse and .webclipse.properties inside c:\users\

After doing all of this, I am back to debugging normally, with Darkest Dark re-installed.